# NullReferenceException vb Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, nullreferenceexception

I always get `NullReferenceException` error when I try to run the this code:

```
Dim startx As Int64
Dim starty As Int64
Dim count As Int64 = 0
Dim Position() As Point
startx = 15
starty = 18
Position(count) = New Point(startx, starty)
```

Can someone tell me why this doesn't work?

Comment: You never initilized `Position` (e.g., `Dim Position() As Point = New Point(10) {}`). Plus, see [Point(Int32, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Point__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_). Declare all your variables as `Integer` (`Int32`) types.

Comment: Thank you I am new to .net and I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

`Position` is declared as an array with 0 items in it. On the last line, you are trying to set the first item (indexed 0), but since there are no items in the array yet, it will fail.

One solution is to declare the array having one item:

```
Dim Position(0) As Point
```

Or, resize the array when needed

```
Dim Position() As Point    

... other code ...

ReDim Preserve Position(0)
```